# ngModel doesn't change the original variable when in a custom directive with ngInclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-include

The variable inside the directive changes but outside the directive it doesn't change. Here is the actual code:

main.html

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in template">
    <fx-widget type="{{row.type}}" value="post[row.name]"></fx-widget>
    {{post[row.name]}}
</div>

app.js

app.directive('fxWidget', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
            $scope.typeUrl = '/partials/' + $attributes.type + '.html';
        },
        template: '<div ng-include="typeUrl"></div>',

    };
});

partials/text.html

<input type="text" ng-model="value">
```

Here are my tests and notes on finding the problem:

1. First I tested to see maybe the ngModel doesn't like binding the value through dictionary/array, so I added the following in main.html:

   ```
   <input ng-model="post[row.name]"> {{post[row.name]}}
   ```

   This one worked.
2. I tested to see if the problem is at ng-include by changing the template variable in the directive:

   ```
   template: '<input ng-model="value">
   ```

   and this one actually worked, so the problem is in ng-include
3. After digging deeper I realized that the ng-include doesn't even send the data back to the directive:

   ```
   template: '<div ng-include="typeUrl"></div> {{value}}'

   // ^^ doesn't work
   ```

   However inside the partial file it works:

   ```
   partials/text.html

   <input type="text" ng-model="value"> {{value}}
   ```

What I am guessing is that `ng-include` creates a copy of the scope and that's why it doesn't change in the parent scope. How can I make it change the scope?

Also an offtopic question. How can I get rid of ng-include alltogether and manually load the partials? The `templateUrl` parameter can accept a function with attributes but it doesn't compile the data binds to actual variables, so that's out of the question.

Thank you!

Comment: You must compile the template, given that its loaded dynamically. This post should help you out: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/

Comment: Thank you! Finally got rid of the ng-include and everything worked out :D